# How to stretch children to fill cross-axis?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a left-right flexbox:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  min-height: 325px; 
  max-height:570px; 
}

.wrapper>.left {
  background: #fcc;
 }

.wrapper>.right {
  background: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the right child is not behaving responsively. To be specific, I want it to fill the height of the wrapper.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: it does fill the height of wrapper! i tested it in Chrome and Firefox and there was no problem. maybe you have simplified your code too much.
you can test this by setting `background-color` for children or setting `align-items: center` in wrapper.

Comment: yea, the height of the wrapper is not filled in safari for some reasons... chrome and firefox does this nicely by setting height: '100%' in the children

Answer (score 335):

- The children of a row-flexbox container automatically fill the container's vertical space.
- Specify `flex: 1;` for a child if you want it to fill the remaining horizontal space:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper>.left {
  background: #fcc;
}

.wrapper>.right {
  background: #ccf;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

- Specify `flex: 1;` for both children if you want them to fill equal amounts of the horizontal space:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper>div {
  flex: 1;
}

.wrapper>.left {
  background: #fcc;
}

.wrapper>.right {
  background: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) is a shorthand property for [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow), [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink), and [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis). `flex: 1;` is equivalent to `flex-grow: 1;`.

Comment: Seems like `align-items: stretch;` is not needed

Comment: how to add gaps 10px. pixel between? =)

Comment: @fdrv, you can use [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/gap) property on the flex container. Note that it isn't yet supported by Safari, but the support is expected to be added sometime soon. Alternatively, you could use `margin-left` on all flex items except the first one.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane `flex: 1` do not do the same thing for me as `flex-grow: 1`. `flex` seems to set the width of my elements to default, while `flex-grow` don't.

Comment: @BarryCap Thanks for the correction. Indeed, `flex: 1;` is actually equivalent to `flex: 1 1 0;` or `flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 0;`, according to the [docs for `flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Answer (score 6):

**short answer:** just use the `flex:1;` for childs

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    .
    .
    .
}
.wrapper > * {
    flex: 1;
}
```

remember that you usually cannot use `width: ...`  and `flex:1;` together for a single child.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only two children in your container (wrapper), so all you want to do is adding display: flex; and justify-content: space-between; instead of playing with the margin.

Regarding the height, you can set the height you want to the parent  (weapper) for example 100px, and then set the height of both children (left and right) to be 100%.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height:100px;
}

.wrapper>.left {
  background: #fcc;
  height:100%;
}

.wrapper>.right {
  background: #ccf;
  height:100%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#children {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

is the right answer. Don't use shorthand properties unless you fully understand (or, care not for) implications.