# Vertically center item with flexbox - align-items: center doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I used the styling from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467660/flexbox-row-how-to-stretch-children-to-fill-cross-axis) to make a progress bar fill in the empty space in a div (only other item is a button).

The problem is now that `align-items: center` doesn't vertically center the progress bar. I tried using `align-content: center` on the child too, with no effect.

Here's the code in case you didn't open the link

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  background: #ccc;
}
.wrapper > .left
{
  background: #fcc;
}
.wrapper > .right
{
  background: #ccf;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

This is how it looks:

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: Code looks good. Should work. There's something else at work here. You should post a demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You mean like this - https://jsfiddle.net/tecpb57f/2/

Comment: The flexbox container is in a Bootstrap column, that's one thing that comes to mind. I'll try and make a reproducible jsfiddle

Comment: I've reproduced the behavior here - https://jsfiddle.net/yd914nzz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do the following to get it right:

1. There is a `margin` coming for the `.progress` element- first you can nullify it:

   ```
   .wrapper > .left > .progress {
     margin: 0;
   }
   ```
2. Give 100% height for `wrapper`
3. I also removed `height: 10vh` for the container of wrapper to finish things up.

See [revised fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4mjogsfy/) and snippet below:

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper > .left {
  background: #fcc;
  flex: 1;
}
.wrapper > .right {
  background: #ccf;
}
.wrapper > .left > .progress {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-s-6 col-s-offset-3" style="background:purple; position:relative; border-radius:10px;">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="35" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:35%">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <button type="button" aside-menu-toggle="menu-1" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Меню</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I finally found that 20px margin from .progress in Chrome Dev tools. Thank you for taking the time, that was exactly the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

A flex container will enable a flex context only to its direct children. Hence, your "progress-bar" div is out of reach. Likewise, your purple background bar is before flex container (wrapper), so don't expect it's content to be centered either. You can check this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Check this code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-s-6 col-s-offset-3" style="background:purple; height:10vh; position:relative; border-radius:10px;">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">
          left
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          right
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pen based on your code [here](http://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/JRkEBy)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

to your `.wrapper` class.

Here is a good article on FlexBox positioning:
https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/