# How do I make all the contents of a Grid item stretch to the bottom, minus the typography?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have four columns in a Grid container, each with the following structure:

```
    <Grid item>
       <Typography>Big Title 1</Typography>
         <Card className={classes.stretchMe}>
            <CardContent>
                Content
            </CardContent>
         </Card>
    </Grid>
```

I would like the Card with class `stretchMe` to stretch to the bottom of the parent Grid item, but because each Card has a Typography component above it, it stretches beyond the height of the parent div.

How do I get all the Cards to stretch to the bottom of the parent Grid item and no further (i.e. minus the height of the Typography)?

Here is a slightly more complex version of the code:

```
import React from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  divider: {
    borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
  },
  stretchMe: {
    height: '100%',
  },
}));

const Cards= () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
      <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3} justify="space-between" alignItems="stretch">
        <Grid item xl={2} lg={2} md={6} xs={12} >
          <Typography variant="h4" >
            Big Title 1 
          </Typography>
          <Card className={classes.stretchMe}>
            <CardContent className={classes.divider}>
              <Typography variant="h6">Little Title 1</Typography>
              <Avatar />
            </CardContent>
            <CardContent className={classes.divider}>
              <Typography variant="h6">Little Title 2</Typography>
              <Typography variant="h4">Content</Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardContent className={classes.divider}>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Typography variant="h6">Little Title 3</Typography>
                  <Typography variant="h4">Content</Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Typography variant="h6">Little Title 4</Typography>
                  <Typography variant="h4">Content</Typography>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xl={4} lg={4} md={6} xs={12} >
          <Typography variant="h4" >
            Big Title 2
          </Typography>
          <Card className="classes.stretchMe">
            <CardContent>Content</CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xl={3} lg={3} md={6} xs={12} >
          <Typography variant="h4" >
            Big Title 3
          </Typography>
          <Card className="classes.stretchMe">
            <CardContent>Content</CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xl={3} lg={3} md={6} xs={12}>
          <Typography variant="h4">
            Big Title 4
          </Typography>
          <Card className="classes.stretchMe">
            <CardContent className={classes.divider}>
              <div className={classes.teamProfile}>
                <Avatar/>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.teamProfile}>
                <Avatar/>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.teamProfile}>
                <Avatar/>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.teamProfile}>
                <Avatar/>
              </div>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```

Many thanks,

Katie

**EDIT**

Here is the problem - the Grid items are stretching beyond the Grid containers
[image]

And here is the desired output:

[image]

My suspicion is that the Big titles are pushing the Cards down?

Comment: Does removing the spacing with the prop `spacing={0}` helps?

Comment: Will you please upload the desired output image?

Comment: Hi roa - I have tried multiple times to add an image (wanted to with my original post) but there seems to be a bug and totally the wrong image is showing up! Any other ideas? I work in a company that blocks most sites - grrrr!

Comment: @FranAcuna - do you mean add spacing={0} to the Grid container? I have tried that and it didn't help unfortunately, but please let me know if I've misunderstood your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @roa - I have been able to put an image here: https://imgur.com/a/G7ruSVH Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the prop as a variable using `JSX`, not as a string. Do:

```
<Card className={classes.stretchMe}>
```

Instead of:

```
<Card className="classes.stretchMe">
```

### UPDATE

1. Use `flex:1` on the cards so they use all the remaining space
2. Set the sub `Grid`s with the `container` and `direction="column"` to that the elements are correctly placed.

The code should look like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    divider: {
    borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`
    },
    stretchMe: {
    height: "100%",
    flex: 1
    }
}));

const Cards= () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
    <Grid
        style={{backgroundColor:"cyan"}}
        container
        xs={12}
        spacing={3}
        justify="space-between"
        alignItems="stretch"
    >
        <Grid container direction="column" item xl={2} lg={2} md={6} xs={12}>
        <Typography variant="h4">Big Title 1</Typography>
        <Card className={classes.stretchMe}>
            <CardContent className={classes.divider}>
            <Typography variant="h6">Little Title 1</Typography>
            <Avatar />
            </CardContent>
            <CardContent className={classes.divider}>
            <Typography variant="h6">Little Title 2</Typography>
            <Typography variant="h4">Content</Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardContent className={classes.divider}>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Typography variant="h6">Little Title 3</Typography>
                <Typography variant="h4">Content</Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Typography variant="h6">Little Title 4</Typography>
                <Typography variant="h4">Content</Typography>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container direction="column" item xl={4} lg={4} md={6} xs={12}>
        <Typography variant="h4">Big Title 2</Typography>
        <Card className={classes.stretchMe}>
            <CardContent>Content</CardContent>
        </Card>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container direction="column" item  xl={3} lg={3} md={6} xs={12}>
        <Typography variant="h4">Big Title 3</Typography>
        <Card className={classes.stretchMe}>
            <CardContent>Content</CardContent>
        </Card>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container direction="column" item xl={3} lg={3} md={6} xs={12}>
        <Typography variant="h4">Big Title 4</Typography>
        <Card className={classes.stretchMe}>
            <CardContent className={classes.divider}>
            <div className={classes.teamProfile}>
                <Avatar />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.teamProfile}>
                <Avatar />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.teamProfile}>
                <Avatar />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.teamProfile}>
                <Avatar />
            </div>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    );
};

export default Cards;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this isn't the issue. You're right that I've not passed it in as a prop, but that was just a typo in copying the code over to stackoverflow. My real code does pass it as a prop. I was thinking  of something along these lines?
https://wpbeaches.com/aligning-last-item-bottom-container-flexbox/  But I would have to have an empty div in each <Card> instead of the button described to force the whole thing to stretch.

Comment: Oh you are right! I thought the problem was that the cards were not stretching, but I colored the grid background and now I see that the cards are extending outside of them.

Comment: Hehe! Well, if you have any brainwaves to solve the problem, I'm still looking for a solution, so do let me know. Many thanks! :)

Comment: I updated the answer, got help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467660/how-to-stretch-children-to-fill-cross-axis).

Comment: Thanks FranAcuna - I felt that I hadn't worded the question very well, so I posted it again. Someone gave a perfect answer which looks the same as yours. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815511/make-child-of-material-ui-grid-item-stretch-to-fit-the-remaining-height-of-the-p?noredirect=1#comment116374894_65815511) Thank you so much! I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you passed the className prop as a string, not a variable.

So, correct format should be `className={classes.stretchMe}`

```js
import React from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    height: "100%"
  },
  divider: {
    borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    "&:last-child": {
      flex: "1"
    }
  },
  stretchMe: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    flex: "1"
  },
  gridItem: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column"
  }
}));

const Cards= () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={3} className={classes.gridItem}>
        <Typography variant="h4">Big Title 1</Typography>
        <Card className={classes.stretchMe}>
          <CardContent className={classes.divider}>
            <Typography variant="h6">Little Title 1</Typography>
            <Avatar />
          </CardContent>
          <CardContent className={classes.divider}>
            <Typography variant="h6">Little Title 2</Typography>
            <Typography variant="h4">Content</Typography>
          </CardContent>
          <CardContent className={classes.divider}>
            <Grid container direction="row">
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Typography variant="h6">Little Title 3</Typography>
                <Typography variant="h4">Content</Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Typography variant="h6">Little Title 4</Typography>
                <Typography variant="h4">Content</Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3} className={classes.gridItem}>
        <Typography variant="h4">Big Title 2</Typography>
        <Card className={classes.stretchMe}>
          <CardContent>Content</CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3} className={classes.gridItem}>
        <Typography variant="h4">Big Title 3</Typography>
        <Card className={classes.stretchMe}>
          <CardContent>Content</CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3} className={classes.gridItem}>
        <Typography variant="h4">Big Title 4</Typography>
        <Card className={classes.stretchMe}>
          <CardContent className={classes.divider}>
            <div className={classes.teamProfile}>
              <Avatar />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.teamProfile}>
              <Avatar />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.teamProfile}>
              <Avatar />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.teamProfile}>
              <Avatar />
            </div>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```

Comment: Thanks roa for your reply. As I have also said to FranAcuna below, this isn't the issue. You're right that I've not passed it in as a prop, but that was just a typo in copying the code over to stackoverflow. My real code does pass it as a prop. I was thinking  of something along these lines?
https://wpbeaches.com/aligning-last-item-bottom-container-flexbox/  But I would have to have an empty div in each <Card> instead of the button described to force the whole thing to stretch.

Comment: It seems that you're going to use custom flexbox. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks roa - ideally I'd be using the Material UI functionality and Grid. Do you know if it's possible to achieve what they're demonstrating in the link above but using Grids instead of custom flexbox? Many thanks again

Comment: I just updated without using flexbox. Please check.

Comment: Thanks roa - I'm still getting the same problem of the Grid items overlapping the parent Grid container. I have added an image of the problem in my original post as the image upload bug now seems to be resolved.

Comment: Updated my answer - but used custom flex.