# Make child of Material UI Grid item stretch to fit the remaining height of the parent container

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

### 1. Current Appearance

I have a Material UI Grid container with 4 Grid items. Within each Grid item is a Typography component containing a title and a Card with some content, as shown below:

[image]

### 2. Desired appearance

I would like the Cards to fill the remaining height of the Grid items and not exceed it. This is my desired output:

[image]

### 3. Undesirable appearance (card height = 100%)

I have tried making the height of the Cards 100% but this means each Card takes on the height of its parent (the Grid item), and the height of the parent = Typography + Card (rather than the remaining space minus the Typography), so the result is that the Card then exceeds the height of the parent Grid item as below:

[image]

What is the best way to overcome this problem? I'm using Material UI's Grid to make the breakpoints easy and consistent with the rest of my project, so ideally the solution would use that approach.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
   // stretch: { height: '100%' }, // Un-commenting this results in undesirable appearance 3 (see image 3 above)
    outline: { border: '1px solid red' },
}));

const Sections= () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={3} justify="space-between" alignItems="stretch" className={classes.outline}>
      <Grid item xl={2} lg={2} md={6} xs={12} className={classes.outline}>
          <Typography className={classes.outline}>Big title 1</Typography>
          <Card className={classes.stretch}><CardContent>Lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of content</CardContent></Card>
      </Grid>
   <Grid item xl={4} lg={4} md={6} xs={12} className={classes.outline}>
          <Typography className={classes.outline}>Big title 2</Typography>
          <Card className={classes.stretch}><CardContent>Not much content</CardContent></Card>
   </Grid>
   <Grid item xl={3} lg={3} md={6} xs={12} className={classes.outline}>
          <Typography className={classes.outline}>Big title 3</Typography>
          <Card className={classes.stretch}><CardContent>Not much content</CardContent></Card>
   </Grid>
   <Grid item xl={3} lg={3} md={6} xs={12} className={classes.outline}>
          <Typography className={classes.outline}>Big title 4</Typography>
          <Card className={classes.stretch}><CardContent>Not much content</CardContent></Card>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
  );
};


export default Sections;
```

Many thanks,

Katie

Comment: I think you are missing some parts of the code. Such as the additional "Big Title"s above each of the cards. Would you be able to update the code snippet to include it? Thanks

Comment: I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dgekds) live example which I believe has your desired outcome. Interestingly, I uncommented the styles you had and it seems to be working. There were some issues where your `<Grid />` tags weren't in the right order so maybe that's why your styling didn't work before.

Comment: Thanks Charles - I have amended the code and hope it now looks correct? I also realise, as you suggest, that there is a closing </Grid> tag in the wrong place. Other than that, I can see that your code is working, but I don't understand the difference? I have had to massively simplify the code shown here vs my own code, so I'm trying to unpick the difference! Do you mind explaining? Many thanks!

Comment: Actually - I can see that I'm afraid that solution doesn't work. If you apply a border to the grids then you can see that it resembles the image 3 above. The Cards extend beyond the height of the parent Grid. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Katie, I realized the issue in my first solution and have updated it. I hope it helps! Thanks for the pictures showing what outcomes were desired.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve this, you need to set a height for each individual Grid Item. Then you can display the Grid Item flexed with the flex-direction of "column". Next, you can set the height of the card to 100% as you had before. The default display mechanism in the Material-UI grid is not set to flex so the card will extend outside of the border since they use things like negative margins.

The code is below:

```
// imports omitted

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  stretch: { height: "100%" },
  item: { display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" } // KEY CHANGES
}));

export const Sections = () => {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2} justify="space-between" alignItems="stretch">
      <Item xl={2} lg={2} md={6} xs={12} title="Big Title 1" content="Lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of content!" />
      <Item xl={4} lg={4} md={6} xs={12} title="Big Title 2" content="Not much content" />
      <Item xl={3} lg={3} md={6} xs={12} title="Big Title 3" content="Not much content" />
      <Item xl={3} lg={3} md={6} xs={12} title="Big Title 4" content="Not much content" />
    </Grid>
  );
}

const Item = ({ title, content, ...rest }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Grid className={classes.item} item {...rest}>
      <Typography>{title}</Typography>
      <Card className={classes.stretch}>
        <CardContent>{content}</CardContent>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

Checkout [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dgekds) for a live example.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! A genius solution to something I have not been able to find a satisfactory answer to! Thank you ever so much. I had been agonising over this for a couple of days so thank you again Charles - brilliant :)

Comment: @charles your stickbliz is giving an error now: 

Error in /~/src/App.js (7:18) 
Unexpected token 'export'

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved the issue in MUIv5

- Set `alignItems="stretch"` on the Grid container
- Set `display="flex"` on each of the Grid items
- Set `width="100%"` for the content inside the Grid item

Example Code:

```
  <Grid container alignItems="stretch">
    <Grid item xl={2} lg={2} md={6} xs={12} display="flex">
      <Box width="100%">
        <Typography>{title}</Typography>
        <Card>
          <CardContent>{content}</CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Box>
    </Grid>
    ....
  </Grid>
```

Comment: ahh, `alignItems="stretch"` is what I needed. it is easy to miss, thank you for sharing this :)

Comment: I think you need to set `height="100%"` for this to work, and not `width`.

Answer (score 0):

to make the `Card` remaining height always, give a height to `Typography`. let's say the height of `Typography` is `20px` and then set the height of the `CardItem` as `100% - (height of the typography_` i.e; `height:'calc(100% - 20px)'. It'll take the remaining height.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    stretch: {
        height: 'calc(100% - 20px)'
    }, // Un-commenting this results in undesirable appearance 3 (see image 3 above)
    outline: { border: "1px solid red" }
}));
```

```
<Grid
  container
  spacing={3}
  justify="space-between"
  alignItems="stretch"
  className={classes.outline}>
  <Grid item xl={2} lg={2} md={6} xs={12} className={classes.outline}>
    <Typography style={{height:'20px'}} className={classes.outline}>Big title 1</Typography>
    <Card className={classes.stretch}>
      <CardContent>
        Lots and lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of content
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xl={4} lg={4} md={6} xs={12} className={classes.outline}>
    <Typography style={{height:'20px'}} className={classes.outline}>Big title 2</Typography>
    <Card className={classes.stretch}>
      <CardContent>Not much content</CardContent>
    </Card>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xl={3} lg={3} md={6} xs={12} className={classes.outline}>
    <Typography style={{height:'20px'}} className={classes.outline}>Big title 3</Typography>
    <Card className={classes.stretch}>
      <CardContent>Not much content</CardContent>
    </Card>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xl={3} lg={3} md={6} xs={12} className={classes.outline}>
    <Typography style={{height:'20px'}} className={classes.outline}>Big title 4</Typography>
    <Card className={classes.stretch}>
      <CardContent>Not much content</CardContent>
    </Card>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: Edit gallant-violet-k9tqs]

Comment: Thank you Rajiv! This is a good answer for anyone who is happy to fix the height of the first child. I have up-voted for that reason. I have marked Charles's answer above as the correct answer as I believe this could cope if the title went over to two lines. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Set container with Red borders to: display: flex

then set the 'not so much content' to flex: 1

flex: 1... is a short hand for flex basis, stretch, shrink

this will stretch 'not so much content' to occupy available space

Answer (score -1):

Setting flexGrow=1 on the grid item and setting parent container to direction column also works, Here's an example,

https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-fermi-cbw7s4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark